# pulling all unique years from datetime fields from a django model

Tags: python, django, datetime, sqlite

running sqlite3 and the defulte datetime field how can I pull all unique years/months/days from the data base without iterating though all entries. Distinct does not appear to work with sqlite3, and without the slow iteration of all the dates I can not think of another way to do this.

to be clear I want to pull all unique values from the database, and not filter to them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The QuerySet method [datetimes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#datetimes) handles this:

```
>>> SomeModel.objects.all().datetimes('date_field', 'year')
[datetime.date(2014, 1, 1), datetime.date(2015, 1, 1)]

>>> [d.year for d in SomeModel.objects.all().datetimes('date_field', 'year')]
[2014, 2015]
```

Updated to use `datetimes` for `DateTimeField` fields. For a `DateField`, use [dates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#dates).

Comment: this helps with datefields not datetimefields